# Mostrar hora del cliente para un evento deportivo

Tags: javascript

Tengo la hora en la comenzará un partido en España, por ejemplo las 15:00
Lo que quiero es que si se abre la pag. en Argentina, con la que España tiene 4 horas, le muestre al lector que ese partido comenzará a las 11:00.
Es decir, que se muestre la hora del partido según la zona horaria desde donde se vea la página.
Si fuera posible con Javascript, mejor.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento?, Checa [ask]

Comment: Javascript debería de devolverte el TimeZone del cliente, después deberías convertir las fechas en función de donde esté

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer eso podría crear un objeto Date utilizando la hora en UTC (deberías calcular antes la hora en UTC, por ejemplo, desde en el servidor), así:

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2020,2,17,15,0,0));
```

Acá le pusimos que el evento es a las 15:00 UTC.  Ahora, si vemos la hora en mi máquina (Argentina) que tengo GMT -3, me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
date.toLocaleString();

"3/17/2020, 12:00:00 PM"
```

Espero te sirva.
Suerte!

Comment: Hola Gustavo. MUCHAS GRACIAS. En base a tu respuesta fuí modificando el script hasta que dí con lo que necesitaba.
Quedó así: var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 5, 26, 15, 0, 0));   

document.write(date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));

Comment: Genial, me alegro!  Por favor, si te sirvió la respuesta márcala.  Gracias!